# how to acquire the a button node by xpath

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, web-crawler

I write a lots of xpath expression to acquire the button node, but all fiailed

A xpath expression to get the button node

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://www.zhihu.com/explore'
browser.get(url)
res=browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/header/div[2]/div[1]/div/button')
#(By.XPATH,'//div[contains(@class,"SearchBar css-10fy1q8")]/form/following-sibling::*[1]') failed
#(By.XPATH,'//div[contains(@class,"SearchBar css-10fy1q8")]/child::*[2]') failed
print(res.text)
```

[image]

Comment: When I visit that site, I see a button inside the form not underneath. And the class of the button  is different: class="Button SearchBar-searchButton random string"